# grant private key access for account NT Authority\Network Service

Tags: x509certificate, digital-certificate

I have a digital certificate from a third party and when I try to run the following ms-dos command to grant access to the NETWORKSERVICE account I am getting the following error.

```
winhttpcertcfg -g-c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "TransUnion Net Access Client" -a "Networkservice"

Error: Unable to update security info for key container error = 0x5.
```

What does that mean? How can I allow my certificate access to the `NT Authority\Network Service` account?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Just for reference I include the following.
I ran this command

```
winhttpcertcfg -l-c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s "TransUnion Net Access Client"
```

Currently only the following accounts have access to the private key:

- `BUILT IN\Administrators`
- `NT AUTHORITY\System`

Comment: As soon as I resolve this problem I hope to be able to tackle this source problem: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I need to **run as administrator** the DOS command prompt and that should do it.

Comment: It's funny - I ran a batch file as administrator, and that failed, but opening the command prompt as administrator and typing in the commands works.